# Looking to search for string in text file

Tags: perl

I'm learning some code and I want to run a subs routine that searches a file. If the name is present I want it to print the name. If the name is not present I want it to print not found. However the problem I am having is that it is printing found when the text is found but not found as so

```
Not found
found Trevor 
Not found
Not found
Not found
found Trevor
```

What I want is the names printed when found but I do not want the not found presented. Likewise when the string is not present I want just one not found printed. I realise the problem is my while loop and if else statements. But I cannot find an arrangement that works the I want it to. Here is my current code;

```perl
sub search(){
open(FILE, "list.txt");
print("\n Search for subscriber\n\n");
my $search = <STDIN>;
while ($line = <FILE>){
if ( $line =~ /$search/) { print "found $search\n" }

else {
    print("Not found \n");
```

#### Edit

The Perl code looks like this. Yes, it is unbalanced by three closing braces

```perl
sub search() {

    open( FILE, "list.txt" );

    print("\n Search for subscriber\n\n");
    my $search = <STDIN>;

    while ( $line = <FILE> ) {

        if ( $line =~ /$search/ ) {
            print "found $search\n";
        }
        else {
            print("Not found \n");
```

Comment: What @toolic said. But your code is horrible to read, and you haven't even posted a section that will compile. You should look at laying out your code properly above anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subroutine is unnecessary and inappropriate for this. However you don't say enough about your circumstances for me to suggest anything better

This works

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use constant LIST_FILE => 'list.txt';

search();

sub search {

    print "\nSearch for subscriber: ";
    chomp( my $search = <> );

    open my $fh, '<', LIST_FILE or die qq{Unable to open "@{[LIST_FILE]}" for input: $!};

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        next unless /\Q$search/;

        print qq{Found "$search"\n};
        return 1;
    }

    print qq{Didn't find "$search"\n};

    return;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand your Q you want to print only once whether a given string, e.g. 'Trevor', is contained in your input file. This is similar to the shell command `grep Trevor list.txt` (or `grep -q`).

@toolic and @borodin already told about `chomp()`. It strips off the trailing `\n` character from your input (`$search`) and is needed because else you are really searching for `Trevor\n` which would only match at the end of a file's line.

If you only want to print *once* then simply add a (boolean) variable, iterate over the file (without printing) and finally print according to the flag. Once the string is found you can stop iterating. This is was the `last;` in the while loop does: it leaves the loop. Further iterations wouldn't change the result, so we can skip them.

There are -- as always in Perl -- many other possibilities to accomplish your task but I tried to stick as close as possible to your attempt.

Putting it together:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub search
{
    print("\n Search for subscriber\n\n");
    my $search = <STDIN>;
    chomp($search);

    my $found = 0;
    open( my $fh, '<', 'list.txt' ) or die "cannot open list.txt: $!\n";
    while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        if ( $line =~ /$search/ ) {
            $found = 1;
            last;
        }
    }
    close($fh);

    if ($found) {
        print "found $search\n";
    } else {
        print "Not found\n";
    }
}
```